# How do you interpret this URL time format?

Tags: xml, url, uri, datetime-format, time-format

I have rather lengthy URL that I am using in an application to receive XML data. I'd like to manipulate the time in the URL based on the users time but I don't know how to interpret it.

Here's the date and time from the URL:

```
2015-04-27T00%3A00%3A00
```

### My Question:

Is there a way to manipulate this to show the current time? For example if I wanted to say that it was 2015-04-27 at 5:30pm CST.

Comment: Does [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) help? Note that `%3A` is just `:` in URL encoding.

Comment: it does actually, so the %3A just represents a colon?

Comment: Yep, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.

Comment: oh, thanks for the link. I can see that wiki page coming very handy in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2015-04-27T00%3A00%3A00` apparently is the [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (conforming to [RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3986.txt)) form of

`2015-04-27T00:00:00` (`%3A` encodes the colon `:`).

This, in turn, is the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) representation for 12:00 AM on April, 27th 2015 UTC.

"2015-04-27 at 5:30pm CST" could hence be represented as

`2015-04-27T17:30:00-06:00` in ISO, or

`2015-04-27T17%3A30%3A00-06%3A00` in URL encoded format.

Comment: great answer, you've answered a few underlying questions I had as well. Thanks again hanno

Comment: The time part (after `T`) being 00:00:00 may indicate though that the server sides operates on dates only and does not value any more precise representation. If there's no documentation, you'd have to try to find out. Just don't be surprised if it does not work right.

Comment: I just tried it out, it's returning data but i haven't looked closely at the XML yet to see if it's starting at midnight or at my specified time.